# Relations and equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, relations

Let $R=\{ (x,y) \vert  x=1 \,\, or\,\,  y=1 \}$

When  I see something written like this to represent "or", I immediately think **XOR**. But is that necessarily true? This would greatly change the relation if only one variable can be 1.

Comment: No: In math, 'or' generally means inclusive or.

Comment: It’s **never** true unless it’s explicitly stated.

Comment: In math generally or mean just or. one of them, or the other, or both.

Comment: This is why people should use the symbol $\vee$ for disjunction and $\oplus$ or $\not \equiv$ for exclusive disjunction.

Comment: @portin.daniel: I’ve never seen $\not\equiv$ used for exclusive or; I’ve seen $\oplus$ and $\underline\lor$.

Comment: We could get really clever if we wrote $\underset{\not\equiv}{\lor}$ for the exclusive or...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In mathematics and in logic, you need to train your mind to *automatically assume* the inclusive-or, and understand that the exclusive sense of "or" holds if and only if the statement explicitly rules out the possibility that both disjuncts are true.

So your relation, $$R=\{ (x,y) \vert  x=1 \,\, \text{or}\,\,  y=1 \} = \{(x, y) \mid x = 1 \lor y = 1\}$$ means that one *or both* members of the ordered pair $(x, y)$ is equal to one. So indeed, $(1, 1) \in R$.

ADDED: You are indeed correct that if $R^*$ were defined so that $$R^* = \{(x, y)\mid x=1 \oplus y = 1\},$$ then it would change the relation considerably:

Specifically, we would have that $R^*$ fails to be reflexive and fails to be transitive, and hence, would not be an equivalence relation, whereas $R$, with the inclusive-or, is indeed an equivalence relation.

$R^*$ fails to be transitive because $(1, 0) \land (0, 1) \in R^*,$ but $(1, 1)\notin R^*$. And since $(1, 1) \notin R^*$, it fails to be reflexive.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I would much prefer standard notation to show the meaning rather than using english.

Comment: @amWhy: Hope you are having a great day! Needs another UV! =1